# Viewing Medical imaging on Mac OS X ?

Tags: snow-leopard, graphics

I am looking for a Software on Mac OS X Snow Leopard capable of viewing DICOM files. DICOM stands for `Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine`.

I found IrfanView on Windows with DICOM PLugin but on MAC I can't found anything.

Comment: Try Mango: http://rii.uthscsa.edu/mango/

Answer (score 6):

Try OsiriX: http://www.osirix-viewer.com

The viewer is free and I used it myself to inspect x ray images.

Answer (score 1):

I found MIPAV Medical Image Processing, Analysis, and Visualization application http://mipav.cit.nih.gov/

it is in java, multi-plateforme.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a [web-based DICOM solution](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-free-HTML-JS-based-DICOM-image-viewers). A famous one is the [Orthanc](https://www.orthanc-server.com/), that I completely recommend. We are using the [Orthanc](https://www.orthanc-server.com/) on our [BreastScreening](https://breastscreening.github.io/) project, a project that joins contributions from both [MIMBCD-UI](https://mimbcd-ui.github.io/) and [MIDA](https://mida-project.github.io/) projects.